# How can I create implicit Intent for file in Android

Tags: java, android

I have a `XML` file on the external storage, and I have different apps which are able to open this file format.

I am going to sent implicit intent like this in order to find apps to open `XML` file:

```
public static boolean isIntentAvailable(Context context, Intent intent) {
    List<ResolveInfo> list = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent,
            PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    return !list.isEmpty();
}
```

This method has 2 arguments. The question is how to create `intent` for second argument?

I have only path to file which I need to open and I tried this way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(**path to file**);
```

But it doesn't work... How can I create this intent properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
File file = new File("path to file");

//checking if the File exists
if (file.exists()) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();

    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "text/xml");

    //checking if an Activity exists that can handle this Intent
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```